# View first MVP (or MVVM) and Framework communication

Tags: mvvm, frameworks, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mvp

ok, I made several thoughts about MVVM/MVP models and how let the triad communicate externally with the rest of the framework/layers and probably the best solution is to use dependency injection.

All that said, my question now is slight different: what if I do not want the presenter to know about the framework but I want the framework to know what to do with the presenter once created?

Just a simple example: if we talk about GUI probably it's not easy to picture, so let's say that my MVVM (or whatever) models an entity in a game.

There is the view (the graphical representation of the entity), there is the model (energy and such) and there is the presenter (how to respond when something happens).

Now, let's say there is a Mediator that manages the communication between the game entities and so wants to know all the game entities being created.

The only way I can see to solve this problem is to let the presenter know, through DI, about the mediator and so let the presenter register itself in the framework mediator.

Although I would rather avoid to let the presenter know about the mediator, since instead I prefer to let the framework know about a new created presenter and register it in the mediator (which should be the IoC principle).

Is that something possible/sensible using a view first approach?

Thank you for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Why inventing a new framework when there are already several that have solved this problem already? Have a look at caliburn micro. Is lets you choose between view first and view model first approaches. And it has support for most IoC containers.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer! I did not want to invent a new framework nor I actually wanted to use an IoC container to wire the dependencies. The question was more a matter of "philosophy", that is why it could have created confusion. I will try to give another example. IoC tells about the Hollywood principle, right? Now, if the presenter must know the framework dependencies to use services and such, it is not following anymore the Hollywood principle. So I was wondering if it has been ever thought about injecting the presenters to the framework in order to apply the H principle.

Comment: Sorry for my blathering, but I just realized where could be the source of my confusion. So far I thought that the ViewModel should have been created by the view itself, instead it is usually wired through several mechanism (IoC containers, DI, ServiceLocator). This actually means that it is not responsibility of the view to create the viewmodel and so the viewmodel should be created by the framework itself. In this way what I want to do makes more sense.